# Using Mule Requester Module in Mule Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I want to use Mule Requester Module as mentioned in http://blogs.mulesoft.org/introducing-the-mule-requester-module.

How to include this is Mule Studio?

Do I need to use --

```
Help > Check for Updates OR 
Help > Install New Software... OR
Should I update pom.xml with the requester module dependency.
```

What is the recommended way?

I guess if I go MuleStudio route it will automatically update pom.xml when I drag Mule Requestor module into my flow.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the zip for Studio from [GitHub](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester). Then extract the zip to a folder somewhere locally and add that local folder (as "file:") in Install New Software -> Add -> Repository. Then install, and you'll have it available in Studio graphical editor. If you use Maven to build, add the dependencies mentioned in the GitHub page.

Answer (score 1):

For MuleStudio

Download the update site zip file from the following location: 
https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-module-requester/1.2/mule-module-requester-1.2-studio-plugin.zip[enter link description here](https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-module-requester/1.2/mule-module-requester-1.2-studio-plugin.zip)
Install it in MuleStudio as a regular update site from a file. The module will appear under the Components tab.
For Maven

Answer (score 0):

Download the zip for Studio from GitHub. Then extract the zip to a folder somewhere locally and add that local folder (as "file:") in Install New Software -> Add -> Repository. Then install, and you'll have it available in Studio graphical editor. If you use Maven to build, add the dependencies mentioned in the GitHub page.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Mule to do this job for you

- Help > install new software
- In "work with" select Anypoint Connectors Update Site
- And type the Connector you are searching for, in this case Requester Mule
- Then you have to click next and just keep clicking next

This [guide](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/installing-connectors) can help you if you have any troubles

Answer (score 0):

go to hellp->install new softeware->choose all sites in the dropdown->and enter mule requestor in search box->you will get the mulerequestor plugin->click next->finish

Answer (score 0):

Better to get it from any ponit studio itself, got to help and then install new software there you have to select all available sites there you can search for mule requester and install it